# All get/put calls error w/"no route matches" in rspec tests; though they work fine in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, routes

Routes that work fine in my application fail on any get/put call in rspec testing with 'No route matches'. What am I doing wrong here?

Here's a simple example, from contracts_controller_spec.rb:

```
it 'should redirect to edit on show' do
  get :show
  response.should be_success
  response.should render_template(:edit)
end
```

The above fails with the following:

```
ContractsController api calls should redirect to edit on show
  Failure/Error: get :show
  ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches {:controller=>"contracts", :action=>"show"}
```

the `show` method in contracts_controller.rb:

```
def show
  Rails.logger.debug("getting contract info....")
  get_contract_info
  Rails.logger.debug("...got contract info.")
  render :action => :edit
end
```

routes.rb content:

```
resource :contract, :only=>[:show, :edit, :update], :protocol =>ROUTES_PROTOCOL do
  member do
    get :print
  end
end
```

`rake routes` output:

```
print_contract GET  /contract/print(.:format)    contracts#print {:protocol=>"http"}
 edit_contract GET  /contract/edit(.:format)     contracts#edit {:protocol=>"http"}
      contract GET  /contract(.:format)          contracts#show {:protocol=>"http"}
               PUT  /contract(.:format)          contracts#update {:protocol=>"http"}
```

- using rspec-rails 2.14.0
- This app was recently upgraded from Rails 2.3 to 3.2, which has otherwise been successful
- note the non-standard show/edit routes: no id is required, and forcing an id still results in `No route matches {:controller=>"contracts", :id=>"1", :action=>"show"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:protocol` is bit weird, try to remove ??

Comment: Aha! We'd been using `ROUTES_PROTOCOL = (Rails.env.production? ? "https" : "http")` in routes.rb to force https in production, but it looks like we can just do `config.force_ssl = true` in production.rb instead. Removing the former cleared out a lot of failing tests; thank you!